# input type text value does not change in jquery alert

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an input text for checking if the corrected values are coming or not in `alert`. But when I open the form and change some value to check whether it takes the updated value in alert. It shows me the old value in alert.

Here is the code

```js
$('#spnFiberLeadLITActual').keyup(function (evt) {
        var neValue = parseFloat($('#spnFiberLeadSpanLength').text());
        var completeValue = $('#spnFiberLeadLITAccepted').text();       

        alert(completeValue); // show the old value not the new value inserted in textbox

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td width="20%"><input type="text" class="text-center" id="spnFiberLeadLITActual" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, this)" /></td>
```

Here is the fiddle for the same

https://jsfiddle.net/49tvu0L8/

Please suggest what is wrong

Comment: you have `onkeypress` as well as `keyup` both. Use only one. Also you missed to add jquery library in both of your code snippet

Comment: Also use `.val()` instead of `text()`

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant: I changed it to `keyup` and also the value in alert is always the previous one. why it doesn't take the latest one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of mistakes:

a) jQuery library missing

b) To get the input box value use `.val()`

c) function `isNumberKey` code is missing.

d) `onkeypress` and `keyup` are both used on the same input. You can use one of them and apply all checks over there only

Working snippet:

```js
$('#spnFiberLeadLITActual').keyup(function(evt) {
  var completeValue = $(this).val();
  console.log(completeValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td width="20%">
  <input type="text" class="text-center" id="spnFiberLeadLITActual" />
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks Alive, it worked as expected.!

Answer (score 1):

use `$('#spnFiberLeadLITAccepted').val()` instead of `$('#spnFiberLeadLITAccepted').text()`

```
$('#spnFiberLeadLITActual').keyup(function (evt) {
    var neValue = parseFloat($('#spnFiberLeadSpanLength').text());
    var completeValue = $('#spnFiberLeadLITAccepted').val();       

    alert(completeValue); // show the old value not the new value inserted in textbox

});
```